# How to place repeatedly a small texture on very large surface?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I want to apply a texture(small image) on a very large plane(100.000 km x 100.000km)

If i do nothing,texture will be too much large.

So i want to apply **repeatedly** the same no large texture in this very large plane.

How to do that?

thanks

Comment: sorry;I'm working on Bender 2.90 and these nodes don't exist !                                        
                                                                                                                                           
 What else did I forget to install to improve compositing?

Comment: Yes.Now no problem.I have just seen that in this version of Blender,these nodes are in the windows Shading.

Answer (score 4):

This should be your basic material for any Image
[image]

To increase the texture size, Simply increase the scale in the mapping node

[image]

**WARNING**  *However with most textures, you will see noticeable tiling*

To reduce the amount of tiling, i suggest looking into Blender Guru's Video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc&feature=emb_title

Comment: To reduce amount of noticeable tiling, if you're lazy to watch the video:
https://imgur.com/a/bRRXDpe

Comment: Just FYI - The UV Texture Coordinate only has X and Y components (representing U and V), so scaling on Z is not necessary.